# How to update my RaspNode? no GUI only CLI

Tags: bitcoind, nodes, raspberry-pi

I would like to know the best way to update my RaspNode (rPi 2 B+) to the 0.12.1 bitcoind version.

I did

> sudo apt-get install bitcoind

I also did this:

Erased /bin/bitcoin folder

then into /bin/

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-upnp-default --disable-wallet
make -j2
```

but it's still the same version 0.11.2

Answer (score 2):

You should uninstall the installed version first completely with `sudo apt-get remove bitcoind` before manually building the binaries from source. Make sure that you backup your wallet (and eventually Blockchain) first (so Keep your data-directory).

Don't run the build in teh `bin` folder! The `sudo make install` command will install more than just the binary on your machine! Use e.g. `/home/git/bitcoin/` to clone the repository and run your `configure` and `make` commands there.

Then instlall bitcoin like described on github. after your `make -j2` command you should run `sudo make install` to install bitcoind on your computer. (Binaries are intalled under `/usr/local/bin/`).

I have installed it on my raspberry Pi a week ago. Works fine :-)

Blockchain-sync lasts almost forever ....

If didn't use the `--disable-wallet` flag. You could use the wallet with `bitcoin-cli`